# C# ASP.NET Is there an alternative to duplicating error checking on every controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

If I have a controller with quite a few actions, doing similar things e.g. Gets data from an api, does something with it, returns view with updated model. Is there a better way to handle errors. Currently I do this on a number of action methods, obviously this duplication doesn't feel right but I can't think of an alternative. Thanks

```
public async Task<IActionResult> method(string id)
{
  var result = await _flightRepository.GetLightById(id);
  if (!result.Valid)
  {
    return View("ErrorPage", result.Error.Message);
  }

  var viewModel = new FlightViewModel
  {
    Flight = result.Result
  };
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

Basically I want to somehow encapsulate the error handling logic to return the error view if valid is false, otherwise populate viewmodel and return view. The valid property returns true if there is an error with the request (this is done in api layer)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you have a base type for the response returned by `GetLightById`? Something like a `IReturn<T>` or something alike?

Comment: a extension method can be a good fit.

Comment: @A.Chiesa yeh it returns a RepositoryResult<T>, The repository result contains the T model and also an error property (with msg and httpstatuscode). This is populated in the repository layer if there is a problem getting the data

Answer (score 1):

If you use a static method like this:

```cs
static async Task<IActionResult> ProcessAsync<T>(
    Func<Task<RepositoryResult<T>>> process, 
    Func<T, IActionResult> ifValid
)
{
    var result = await process();
    if (!result.Valid)
    {
        return View("ErrorPage", result.Error.Message);
    }
    
    return ifValid(result.Result);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```cs
public Task<IActionResult> method(string id)
{
    return ProcessAsync(
        () => _flightRepository.GetLightById(id),
        flight =>
        {
            var viewModel = new FlightViewModel
            {
                Flight = flight
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
    );
}
```

The static method can be defined anywhere you wish - in a base Controller class, or in a different namespace entirely (in which case you would import it with `using static Some.Namespace.With.Class;`.

Additionally, I suggest you use the convention of an `Async` suffix for asynchronous methods - so because `GetLightById` returns `Task<T>` I suggest renaming it `GetLightByIdAsync`.

Comment: Thanks I think this and the other answer are both viable solutions, however I wonder if it's also overkill and more readable to just duplicate the code... but DRY arrrghhh

Comment: Yeah, and of course if you ever wanted to add some additional standard verification, you'd have to copy/paste that too, so it's usually better to run everything through one method (or filter like the other answer).

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to reuse code among your actions.

For example in your case your filter could be:

```
public class FlightValidator: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _flightIdRouteKey; // e.g 23
    private readonly string _errorViewName; // e.g "ErrorPage"
    private readonly IFlightRepository _flightRepo;

    public FlightValidator(string flightIdRouteKey, string errorViewName, IFlightRepository flightRepository)
    {
        _flightIdRouteKey = flightIdRouteKey;
        _errorViewName = errorViewName;
        _flightRepo = flightRepository;
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        int flightId = (int)context.RouteData.Values[_flightIdRouteKey];

        var result = await _flightRepo.GetFlightById(flightId);
        if (!result.Valid)
        {
            context.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = _errorViewName, 
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(result.ViewData)
                {
                    Model = model
                }
            };
            return;
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Now you can use the filter like this:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(FlightValidator), Arguments = new object[] { "id", "ErrorPage"})]
public async Task<IActionResult> method(string id)
{
  var viewModel = new FlightViewModel
  {
    Flight = result.Result
  };

  return View(viewModel);
}
```

I suggest you to refer [Filters docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more information about filters.

Comment: Thanks I think this and the other answer are both viable solutions, however I wonder if it's also overkill and more readable to just duplicate the code... but DRY arrrghhh

Comment: DRY make your code clean , maintainable and scalable, and saves you lots time when you reuse the code in different places.